# Zip contents of some subfolders but not others

Tags: zip

I would like to use the unix zip command to zip a directory. Let's say the directory is structured as follows:

```
dir1/
dir1/dir2/
dir1/dir2/file1
dir1/dir2/file2
dir1/dir3
dir1/dir3/file1
dir1/file1
dir1/file2
```

I would like to zip `dir1` into `dir1.zip` such that `dir1.zip` contains `dir1/file1, dir1/file2, dir1/dir2/file1, dir1/dir2/file2, dir3/`, but NOT `dir1/dir3/file1`. In short, I'd like to zip all of the FILES under `dir1`, `dir2` and all of its files, and `dir3` but NONE of its files.

If I do `zip dir1 dir1/`, it will zip everything in `dir1`, all of its files and subfolders but not the contents of the subfolders. If I do `zip -r dir1 dir1/`, it will zip everything in `dir1`, including all of its files and all of the files of its subfolders. I would like to be able to control which subfolders should be zipped recursively and which shouldn't.

Thanks.

Comment: It looks to me like you could use the `-i` option. Does that not work for you?

Answer (score 4):

```
$ zip -r dir1 dir1 -x dir1/dir3/*
```

works for me. Here `-x` is the exclude option. You could also use an include option, but in this case, the exclude option involves less typing.

Actually the question is not completely clear. Do you want all directories and files under `dir3` excluded as well, or just the files under `dir3`? The command above only works for the latter.

Comment: This is not a great general solution because `zip` will only exclude everything that exactly matches the paths specified by `-x`, even if you pass an escaped wildcard. It will still descend into all subdirectories of excluded dirs, and include any files within those.

Answer (score 2):

One method to work with archive files is to mount them, and then access them like normal directories. [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) is available for [most unices](http://apps.sourceforge.net/mediawiki/fuse/index.php?title=OperatingSystems) and supports several [filesystems to access compressed files transparently](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/fuse/index.php?title=CompressedFileSystems). For zip files, possibilities include [fuse-zip](http://code.google.com/p/fuse-zip/) ([AVFS](http://avf.sourceforge.net/) is also convenient but read-only).

For example, with fuse-zip, here's how to mount the archive and copy the files into it.

```
mkdir tmp
fuse-zip /path/to/zip tmp
rsync -av --exclude='/dir1/dir3/*' dir1 tmp/
fusermount -u tmp; rmdir tmp
```

Comment: Interesting approach. i know `mc` also has support for creating virtual filesystems for archives.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command from the parent directory of dir1:

```
tar --exclude=dir3/* -cf - dir1/ | zip dir1.zip -
```

And to unzip dir1.zip use this command:

```
unzip -p dir1.zip | tar xf -
```

Answer (score 0):

The only robust way is to pass `zip` a list of the files you want to archive, e.g.:

```bash
find dir1 \! \( -path dir1/dir3 -prune \) | sort | zip dir1.zip -@
```

This ensures that the archive will contain neither the excluded directory nor any of its descendants. The argument to `-path` must exactly match what `find` outputs for that directory. See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/634037/161288) for how to prune multiple dirs.