# How to properly exclude directories in find?

Tags: find, directory

According to this question: [How to exclude dirs in find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210042/how-to-exclude-a-directory-in-find-command?page=1&tab=active#tab-top), the command should be this:

```
find . -type d \( -path dir1 -o -path dir2 -o -path dir3 \) -prune -o -print
```

But if I do

```
find . -type d \( -path "./.cpan" -o -path "./.mozilla" -o "./.cache" \) -prune -o -print
```

That gives:
`find: paths must precede expression: ./.cache'`

`find: possible unquoted pattern after predicate -o'?`

but I did quotes.

Also, after `-path` option, does the path should be absolute or relative? Because I have included the current dir `./[somefile]`, but is it needed for `-path`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've missed the `-path` predicate in front of the last option value `"./.cache"`

The path used with `-path` must begin with the top-level search path used by `find`. For example

- `find . -path './something/here'`
- `find /etc -path '/etc/init.d'`

You may need to use the `*` wildcard if you want to match a directory name without specifying its position in the filesystem tree. This example will match all files (`-type f`) somewhere under the directory `wizard`

- `find . -path '*/wizard/* -type f -print`

Comment: Ok, but how is it with the paths?

Comment: @Herdsman You are correctly using `-path` in that second command.

Comment: @Kusalananda what makes you say that? Herdsman is missing a `-path` instruction in the bracketed clause

Comment: I believe I was referring to the use of complete pathnames, including the top-level path `./`, in the `-path` arguments in the second command, which they did not use in the first. In this sense, they were using `-path` correctly in the second command and not in the first. I don't think I spotted the missing `-path` test in front of the last path.  Se also my edit to your answer, which relates to this.

Comment: @Kusalananda ah thank you

Answer (score 1):

For future readers, the POSIX compliant solutions that **do not traverse the excluded directories and do not include them in the output at all** have the general formats:

Single exclusion

```bsh
find searchpath \! \( -path searchpath/excludepath -prune \)
```

Multiple exclusions

```bsh
find searchpath \! \( \( -path searchpath/excludepath1 -o -path searchpath/excludepath2 -o -path 'searchpath/excludepathprefix-*' \) -prune \)
```

Preventing that traversal can make a *huge* improvement on performance when those directories contain many files. Complete omission of excluded directories from output prevents unintentionally operating on them.

Further filters and output parameters can be placed *after* all of those shown, except those such as `-maxdepth` which are always placed immediately after `searchpath`. The arguments to `-path` must match what `find` would output for that directory, and wildcards must be escaped/quoted.

---

For this question, the solution would be this (since `-print` is the default):

```bsh
find . \! \( \( -path ./.cpan -o -path ./.mozilla -o -path ./.cache \) -prune \)
```

Comment: The only correct answer and no upvotes...

Answer (score 0):

I come to this page when I search for info to make the find command exclude multiple directories. I find the answer of [Walf](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/161288/walf) the most elegant. From my experiment, a variation based on the same concept is:

```
find . \( -path ./.cpan -o -path ./.mozilla -o -path ./.cache \) -not -prune -o -print
```